# Magento: item stock availability configuration

Tags: magento, inventory, inventory-management

I would like to know, in Magento, when one configures the inventory
related to a given product, one can go to the following:

> Magento Admin Panel -> Catalog -> Manage Products -> Click on Product
>   -> Product Information -> Inventory

where a property called "Stock Availability" can be set. I have read
that this property allows the product to show up as in stock in the
backend even when out of stock in the frontend (found this info in
the book Mastering Magento by Brett Williams).

Shouldn't it be the other way round (item shows up in stock on the
frontend even when out of stock on the backend)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing - i think you are asking how to display out of stock products on the frontend (if not can you please clarify things?).

So, to allow out of stock products to be visible on frontend, first go to admin area and then to: `System > Configuration`

From there, find the `Catalogue` tab on the left and click on the `Inventory` option.

The go to Stock `Options > Display Out of Stock Products`

- **Yes** = Show Products on frontend regardless of their stock status
- **No**  = Hide Out of Stock products

To confirm, The `Stock Availability` setting that you mentioned in the `Catalog -> Manage Products -> Click on Product -> Product Information -> Inventory` section will allow you to manually set a product to out of stock - regardless of the actually inventory level.  For example, say you have a product with 100 units in stock.  If you set the Stock Availability to "Out of Stock" then this will force the item to be out of stock.

Comment: OK, the description in the book was not clear, but your explanation was clear. Basically, the Catalog -> Manage Products -> Click on Product -> Product Information -> Inventory -> Stock Availability can force an item to appear out of stock on the frontend even when the magento inventory sais there are a positive number of items available. On the contrary, which is what you point out, it is possible to configure magento under System -> Configuration -> Options -> Display out of Stock Products to YES to enable items which have no stock count in the database to still show up on the frontend.

Comment: Presumably these show up because the seller/merchant intends to carry out backorders.

Comment: Yes correct, aside from: "items which have no stock count" should be "items which are out of stock" - as they can be out of stock due to stock level or stock availability set to "no"